# MATLAB How can I change some specific number 01 to 10 for a loop?

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, numbers

Below code is my code.

I want to change s01 to s10 in 3rd row and 18th row. (I noted those)

First and last row

> *for and end* function

are just my try.

```
for i=1:10; % I don't need to only use this

M=dlmread('a02_s01_e02_skeleton.txt', ' '); % here s01 have to change s01, s02,..., s10
M(any(M'==40),:) =[];
K = M - kron(M(1:40:end,:), ones(40,1));

    for ii=1:20

    start = 2 + (ii-1)*2;
    K1=K(start:40:end,1);
    K2=K(start:40:end,2);

    subplot(2,1,1); plot(K1); xlabel('frame'); ylabel('x'); grid on;
    subplot(2,1,2); plot(K2); xlabel('frame'); ylabel('y'); grid on;

    frm = getframe( gcf );

    targetFolderName = 'C:\Users\kanje\Desktop\graph\a02_s01_e02';  
    % here also change s01 to s10

    imwrite( frm.cdata, fullfile( targetFolderName, sprintf( 'con%d.jpg', ii ) ) ); 

    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following changes:

```
M=dlmread(['a02_s' num2str(i,'%02.f') '_e02_skeleton.txt'], ' ')
```

what this does is concatenate three strings, where the middle one changes from 01 to 10.  The num2str will return a string of two characters with leading zeros if the number is only one digit.

For the second string use the same technique as this one.

```
targetFolderName = ['C:\Users\kanje\Desktop\graph\a02_s' num2str(i,'%02.f') '_e02'];
```

Comment: Can u write second string for me?? 
Is there need [ ] ??

Comment: targetFolderName = 'C:\Users\kanje\Desktop\graph\['a02_s' num2str(i,'%02.f') '_e02']'; like this?

Comment: The way to concatenate strings is [str1 str2 str3]. For the second case you should place the opening bracket at the start of the string

Comment: Can u help me about my another posted question?